# Выбрать данные из базы данных django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Как выбрать пост из базы данных по id который поступает в функцию post_view? В return видно элементы которые нужны, была идея делать как profile, но получается какой то неправильный вариант

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()


class Group(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField("date published", auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               related_name="posts")
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                              related_name="posts", null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pub_date']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

from .models import Post, Group, User


def index(request):
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(post_list, 10)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    return render(
        request,
        'index.html',
        {'page': page, }
    )


def group_posts(request, slug):
    group = get_object_or_404(Group, slug=slug)
    posts_list = group.posts.all()
    paginator = Paginator(posts_list, 10)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    return render(request, "group.html", {"group": group, "page": page})


def profile(request, username):
    author = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    posts_list = author.posts.all()
    paginator = Paginator(posts_list, 10)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    post_count = paginator.count
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'author': author,
                                            'page': page,
                                            'count': post_count})


def post_view(request, username, post_id):
    pass
    """return render(request, 'post.html', {'author': author,
                                         'post': post,
                                         'count': post_count})"""
```

Comment: @RomanKonoval сформулировал. вроде бы более правильная формулировка

Answer (score 1):

```
Model.objects.get(id=post_id)
```

*Так надо?*

Comment: Почти так. Немного по другому сделал, в данном случае он делал выборку даже если пост не принадлежит пользователя, не знаю как это работало.
post = get_object_or_404(Post.objects.select_related('author'),
                             id=post_id, author__username=username)
Так получилось

Comment: проблема, как я понимаю решена?

Comment: Получается что так